# Case_when adding on a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to write a function in R that generates three values that loops over each row of a df, checks the value of one column then, if it meets this condition, adds the value of the value of one column for this row to a value.

I thought that using the `case_when` construction would work best for this, but should I be using an lapply constructon instead ?

```
get_home_away_goals_for_team <- function(matches_df, team_list){
  
  complete_df <- data.frame(team = character(), goals_scored= double(),goals_conceded = double(), games_played = double())
  
  for (team in teams){
  
  print(team)

  goals_scored <- 0 
  goals_conceded <- 0
  games_played <- 0 
  
  case_when(
    matches_df$home == team ~ goals_scored = goals_scored + matches_df$hg,
    matches_df$home == team ~ goals_conceded = goals_conceded + matches_df$ag,
    matches_df$away == team ~ goals_scored = goals_scored + matches_df$ag,
    matches_df$away == team ~ goals_conceded = goals_conceded + matches_df$hg,
    matches_df$home == team ~ games_played = games_played + 1,
    matches_df$away == team ~ games_played = games_played + 1)
  
    temp_get_goals_df = data.frame(team,goals_scored,goals_conceded,games_played)
    
    complete_df <- rbind(complete_df,temp_get_goals_df)
    }
  
  complete_df
  
}
```

The function takes a value of team, checks for each row whether this team was playing in a game home or away, then adds to the values of `goals scored` accordingly.

When I try to use the function though, I get the error `Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"` which makes me think I'm using `case_when` incorrectly.

Is this the case ?

Data:

matches_df_example :

```
structure(list(home = c("Colorado Rapids", "Vancouver Whitecaps", 
"DC United", "Los Angeles Galaxy", "San Jose Earthquakes", "FC Dallas"
), away = c("Columbus Crew", "Club de Foot Montreal", "Sporting Kansas City", 
"Real Salt Lake", "New England Revolution", "New York Red Bulls"
), res = c("H", "H", "A", "A", "H", "H"), season = c(2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), hg = c(2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2), ag = c(0, 
0, 1, 3, 0, 1), date_time = structure(c(1331420400, 1331420400, 
1331425800, 1331436600, 1331436600, 1331492400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), home_conference = c("West", "West", "East", "West", 
"West", "West"), away_conference = c("East", "East", "East", 
"West", "East", "East")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

teams

```
c("Colorado Rapids", "Vancouver Whitecaps", "DC United", "Los Angeles Galaxy", 
"San Jose Earthquakes", "FC Dallas", "Chivas USA", "Portland Timbers", 
"Club de Foot Montreal", "Sporting Kansas City", "Real Salt Lake", 
"Seattle Sounders", "Philadelphia Union", "Toronto FC", "Columbus Crew", 
"New England Revolution", "Chicago Fire", "New York Red Bulls", 
"Houston Dynamo", "Orlando City", "New York City", "Atlanta United", 
"Minnesota United", "Los Angeles FC", "FC Cincinnati", "Atlanta Utd", 
"Nashville SC", "Inter Miami", "Austin FC")
```

Comment: The `goals_scored =` inside the `case_when` would create syntax issue.  You may need to do the assignment outside the `case_when`

Comment: How would that assignment work? I've looked for example but couldn't find any ! Thanks !

Comment: I believe you are creating multiple columns.  If that is the case you may want to add multiple case_when statements for each column created i.e. `matches_df %>% mutate(goals_scored = case_when(
    home == team ~ goals_scored + hg),goals_conceded =  case_when( home == team, goals_conceded + ag), ....)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```r
homes <- matches_df %>%
  group_by(team = home) %>%
  summarize(
    goals_scored = sum(hg),
    goals_conceded = sum(ag),
    games_played = n(),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
aways <- matches_df %>%
  group_by(team = away) %>%
  summarize(
    goals_scored = sum(hg), 
    goals_conceded = sum(ag), 
    games_played = n(), 
    .groups = "drop"
  )

full_join(homes, aways, by = "team", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  full_join(tibble(team = teams), by = "team") %>%
  transmute(
    team, 
    goals_scored = coalesce(goals_scored, goals_scored.y, 0), 
    goals_conceded = coalesce(goals_conceded, goals_conceded.y, 0), 
    games_played = coalesce(games_played, games_played.y, 0)
  )
# # A tibble: 29 x 4
#    team                   goals_scored goals_conceded games_played
#    <chr>                         <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1 Colorado Rapids                   2              0            1
#  2 DC United                         0              1            1
#  3 FC Dallas                         2              1            1
#  4 Los Angeles Galaxy                1              3            1
#  5 San Jose Earthquakes              1              0            1
#  6 Vancouver Whitecaps               2              0            1
#  7 Club de Foot Montreal             2              0            1
#  8 Columbus Crew                     2              0            1
#  9 New England Revolution            1              0            1
# 10 New York Red Bulls                2              1            1
# # ... with 19 more rows
```